# getting value error in invalid literal for int variable

Tags: python, for-loop, input, integer, append

Hey I am trying to take the int variable as input but I am getting value

```
val = int(input())
nums = []
for i in range(val):
    n = int(input())
    nums.append(n)
```

Comment: The value being passed to *int()* cannot be interpreted as a base 10 integer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].